# hola buen dia me podrian revisar como solucionar este problema porfavor y gracias

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, localhost

si me podrian revisar el error que tengo porque ya lo revise y no doy como resolver el error porfavor revisenlo y me avisan porfavor y gracias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no se como enseñaselo porque se supone que es un formulario en sublime text con conexion a una base de datos a ver si esto les ayuda mas fotos esta es mi base de datos [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi codigo donde esta el error

```html
$id_admin=$_POST['id_admin'];
$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
$apaterno=$_POST['apaterno'];
$amaterno=$_POST['amaterno'];
$telefono=$_POST['telefono'];

require("conexion.php");
$inserta = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO administradores VALUES('$id_admin','$nombre','$apaterno','$amaterno','$telefono')");
```

Comment: Tienes que mostrar el código que generó el error que muestras.

Comment: Te aviso, acabo de revisar el error y efectivamente tienes un problema, el cual se encuentra en el archivo alta_admin.php, en las lineas 3, 4, 5, 6 y 7. Dicho esto, sin más contexto, poco más se te puede ayudar sin jugar a las adivinanzas pues no has puesto un [example] con el que guiarnos ni nos das un contexto de cuando ocurre, y poder darte una respuesta más certera. Léete [ask] para aprender a realizar buenas preguntas con mejores títulos descriptivos ("tengo un problema" no es un buen título para que nadie te ayude). Suerte!

Comment: Con la información que nos das, lo único que podemos indicarte es que, entre las líneas 3 y 7, haces uso de un array asociativo cuyos índices `id_admin, nombre, apaterno, amaterno y teléfono` aún no has inicializado

Comment: Ahora la pregunta ha mejorado, aun así estaria bien ver el formulario HTML tambien, gracias por intentarlo. A ver, sin más datos, y haciendo ejercicios de adivinación, se me ocurre que estás intentando abrir ese PHP directamente sin enviar datos del formulario, y por eso te da ese error. Si quieres evitar eso puedes cambiar todas las asignaciones de los POST por algo así: `$id_admin=(isset($_POST['id_admin']))?$_POST['id_admin']:'';` y encerrar el `require` y el `$inserta` en un `if(!isset($_POST['id_admin'])) {}` para evitar que se ejecute si no recibe datos, sino dara error tambien.